# Automatically convert all the identifiers in appropriate case

Tags: rust, camelcasing, rust-analyzer

So for example,

```rust
pub enum Format {
    Undefined,
    R4g4UnormPack8,
    R4g4b4a4UnormPack16,
    B4g4r4a4UnormPack16,
    R5g6b5UnormPack16,
    B5g6r5UnormPack16,

    R5G5B5A1_UNORM_PACK16,
    B5G5R5A1_UNORM_PACK16,
    A1R5G5B5_UNORM_PACK16,
    R8_UNORM,
    //...
    G10X6_B10X6_R10X6_3PLANE_420_UNORM_3PACK16,
    //...
}
```

The first 6 lines are converted by me using `rust-analyzer` code action for each line manually.

But as you can guess the list is very long and I'm searching for a way to do these all.
Like when building it warns me to convert it.

```
warning: variant `G10X6_B10X6_R10X6_3PLANE_420_UNORM_3PACK16` should have an upper camel case name
   --> src/core.rs:388:5
    |
388 |     G10X6_B10X6_R10X6_3PLANE_420_UNORM_3PACK16,
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: convert the identifier to upper camel case: `G10x6B10x6R10x6_3plane420Unorm3pack16`
```

And I also want to convert it. Is there a way to accomplish this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to fix it with `rustfix` but according to [github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8806), this lint is filtered out, it can be included via setting env var([ref](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfix/issues/163)).

for Windows:

```
set __CARGO_FIX_YOLO="yolo"
cargo fix
```

for Unix based:

```
export __CARGO_FIX_YOLO="yolo"
cargo fix
```

**Important :**

Please note that this will try to fix everything in your source, this may bring an unwanted side effects, you may want to check [cargo fix ref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-fix.html) or you can do some little hack by copying your structures to plain new project then re-add into your project after fixing.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on my implementation after asked the question. I guess it works.

Here is my code.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum CharClass {
    Alphabetic,
    Digit,
}

fn convert(text: &str) -> String {
    let mut previous = None;
    let mut current = CharClass::Alphabetic;

    let mut result = String::with_capacity(text.len());

    result.push_str(text.get(..1).unwrap());
    for ch in text.chars().skip(1) {
        match previous {
            // `previous` is only `Some` if encountered '_'.
            Some(t) => {
                match t {
                    CharClass::Alphabetic => {
                        if ch.is_ascii_alphabetic() {
                            current = CharClass::Alphabetic;
                        } else if ch.is_ascii_digit() {
                            current = CharClass::Digit;
                        }
                        result.push(ch);
                    }
                    CharClass::Digit => {
                        if ch.is_ascii_alphabetic() {
                            current = CharClass::Alphabetic;
                            result.push(ch);
                        } else if ch.is_ascii_digit() {
                            current = CharClass::Digit;
                            result.push('_');
                            result.push(ch);
                        }
                    }
                }
                previous = None;
            }
            None => {
                if ch.is_ascii_alphabetic() {
                    current = CharClass::Alphabetic;
                    result.push(ch.to_ascii_lowercase());
                } else if ch.is_ascii_digit() {
                    current = CharClass::Digit;
                    result.push(ch);
                } else if ch == '_' {
                    previous = Some(current);
                } else {
                    result.push(ch);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        "G10x6B10x6R10x6_3plane420Unorm3pack16",
        &convert("G10X6_B10X6_R10X6_3PLANE_420_UNORM_3PACK16")
    );

    assert_eq!(
        "Astc12x12SfloatBlockExt",
        &convert("ASTC_12x12_SFLOAT_BLOCK_EXT")
    );
}
```